# Google Script - Adding dynamic parameters to href from handler

Tags: dynamic, google-apps-script, href

I have a Google Script published as a web app which uses UI service to display an interface with several listboxes.  I can get at the values selected thru server handlers.

My problem is that I need to add these values to a url in a anchor defined in my doGet routine.  (I am calling a JotForm url, and need the dynamic parameters to pre-populate the form)

I can't see how to modify the anchor from the handler function, or any other way to invoke the url I build in code.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to modify any widget in a Ui created with [UiApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/ui-app), each widget must have an ID that you can use to `getElementById()` and manipulate the way you want just as if you were in the `doGet` function.

Here is a simple example to illustrate : ([online here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyYHRzynSubnhNhc06XdYJY2A01sM65LU1BZsML6AU6886phu0/exec))

```
function doGet(){
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('test');
  var serieNames = ['  serie A','  serie B','  serie C'];
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel().setStyleAttribute('padding','30px');
  var namesHandler = app.createServerHandler('showPilots').addCallbackElement(panel);
  for(var n in serieNames){
    var serieSelect = app.createRadioButton('pilotSelect',serieNames[n]).setId('s'+n).addClickHandler(namesHandler)
    panel.add(serieSelect);
  }
  app.add(panel);
  return app;
}


function showPilots(e){
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));// you can see the source parameter in e that returns the widgets ID of the button you clicked to call the handler
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var serie = e.parameter.source; // get the ID
  app.add(app.createLabel('you clicked '+e.parameter.source));// then get this widget by its ID and modify it
  app.getElementById(serie).setText('Clicked');// modify it
  return app;// update Ui
}
```

---

**EDIT :** here is a version that manipulates anchors, it is perfectly possible to change the url from a handler.

[test here](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycby306FH9G6Jyd2x3-LYD4xNQwhh2Vt9HldSh3ZwoIzLp27grO7i/exec)

### code :

```
function doGet(){
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('test');
  var links = ['link 1','  link 2','  link 3'];
  var linkshref = ['http://www.google.com','http://www.packtpub.com/google-apps-script-for-beginners/book','http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script'];
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel().setStyleAttribute('padding','30px');
  var namesHandler = app.createServerHandler('changeUrl').addCallbackElement(panel);
  for(var n in links){
    var linkWidget = app.createAnchor(links[n], linkshref[n]).setId('s'+n);
    panel.add(linkWidget);
  }
  var btn = app.createButton('change links',namesHandler);
  app.add(panel.add(btn));
  return app;
}


function changeUrl(e){
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));// you can see the source parameter in e that returns the widgets ID of the button you clicked to call the handler
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var links = ['New link 1','New link 2','new link 3'];
  var linkshref = ['http://www.microsoft.com','http://www.w3schools.com/js/','https://sites.google.com/site/appsscriptexperiments/'];
  for(var n in links){
    app.getElementById('s'+n).setHref(linkshref[n]).setHTML(links[n]);
  }
  return app;// update Ui
}
```

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't appear you can change the target of an anchor from a handler routine.  I can change the display text, but I get an error if I attempt to use .setTarget in the handler.  If the target url of an anchor can't be changed from a handler routine, how can anchors ever be used when run time parameters need to be added?